# NoSuchElementException with uiautomator2

Tags: python, appium, android-uiautomator, saucelabs

I'm trying to run my Python code on Sauce Labs and it works fine with `automationName` capability not set (which defaults it to `Appium` as per http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/). However, when I set this capability to `UiAutomator2`, it throws below error at the line `element_some_text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Some Text']")`:

`NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.`

Here's my code:

```
import lemoncheesecake.api as lcc
from appium import webdriver


@lcc.suite("My test suite")
class my_test_suite:
    caps = {}
    driver = None

    def setup_suite(self):
        self.caps['appiumVersion'] = "1.8.1"
        self.caps['deviceName'] = "Android GoogleAPI Emulator"
        self.caps['deviceOrientation'] = "portrait"
        self.caps['platformVersion'] = "7.1"
        self.caps['platformName'] = "Android"
        self.caps['automationName'] = 'uiautomator2'
        self.caps['autoGrantPermissions'] = True
        self.caps['app'] = 'https://somesite.com/storage/my_app.apk'
        self.caps['appPackage'] = 'com.xxx.abc.my_app'
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
            'http://username:passkey@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub', self.caps)

    @lcc.test("My app test")
    def verify_app_launch(self):
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        element_some_text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Some Text']")
        element_some_text.click()

    def teardown_suite(self):
        self.driver.quit()
```

Comment: TRY explicit wait using Expected conditions class once and see if issue still persists

Comment: Why shall I even bother about using `ExpectedConditions` class when the same code works with `Appium` automationName?

Comment: NoSuchElementException can occur for 2 reasons either locator is wrong or synchronization issue, with implicit wait the is fix for 10 sec but it may be happening that locator being xpath is taking more time, so you can try with increase time out....
You are saying same code works when u use automationName= 'UIAutomator' ?

Comment: I'm saying that my code works with the default `automationName` which is `Appium` as per http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/. And it does not work with `automationName=UiAutomator2`. Also, I tried increasing the implicit wait to 30 seconds, but that did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the explicit wait on the invisibility of an element (defined below) appearing prior to the required `Some Text` element resolved the issue. **Strangely though**, this explicit wait was not required in case of the default `automationName`.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "com.xxx.abc.my_app:id/prior_element")))
```

PS: While I understand this answer might get a few downvotes, I strongly believe this is a strange behaviour from the `UiAutomator2` engine.